# How can I get index() of the hovered children under its own parent?

Tags: jquery, hover

I have this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/fnjd4fpj/5/):

```
<div class="fascia">
    <div class="navigator">
        <div class="item">Item 0</div>
        <div class="sibling">sibling</div>
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>          
        <div class="sibling">sibling</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="navigator">
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="sibling">sibling</div>
        <div class="item">Item 4</div>
        <div class="sibling">sibling</div>
        <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

```js
var navigators = $('.fascia .navigator');
navigators.find('.item').hover(
    function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var index = elem.index(".item");
        navigators.find(".item:eq(" + index + ")").addClass("hover");
    }, function () {
    }
);
```

but when I hover Item 4, I need to get index 1, not 4. So get the index due to the children of the current parent, not "all" children in the dom. Of course I want to preserve `navigators` variable, so the hover handler is unique to all elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `index()` without any parameter:

```
var navigators = $('.fascia .navigator');
navigators.find('.item').hover(
    function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var index = elem.index();
        console.log(index);
    }, function () {
    }
);
```

From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

---

**As per your updated question:**

You can use like this:

```
var index = $(this).parent().children('.item').index(this);
```

Here we first grab the parent element and select its children with class item which is only required to be indexed and use the index(this) to get the index.

Thanks to @ArunPJohny.

Comment: I can't do it, because I could have other elements inside it (sorry, forgot to mention). Edited the question!

Comment: i.e. I need index of `.item` order, not with other elements alongside them.

Comment: Sorry, but your edit is confusing me. Please do a proper indentation to your html. (anyways, I am going home, will check tomorrow.).

Comment: I need to return the index of each `item` (due to its parent) ignoring other elements (in this case, `.sibiling`). So, even if there are other elements, take the index of pure `.item`

Comment: I think Arun P Johny give me the answer: `var index = $(this).parent().children('.item').index(this);`

Comment: @markzzz I was in hurry yesterday. Anways good to know you got the answer. Since ArunPJohny has deleted the answer I will update the answer.